# displaying a particular field of a related node with Entity Reference

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, cck

Using Drupal 7, using views i have created a related 'videos' block for various page nodes. I can get the title to show but i can't see how i can just choose to show the 'thumbnail' field for related videos. I'm using the entity reference module. Is this possible within the view?

heres the example...http://testing.odvod.ca/bishop/what-we-do/our-approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out...
in the view i created a relationship choosing:
--Entity Reference: Referenced Entity
--A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_related_videos

The added the field to view and chose the reference the desired field content with the relationship drop down.

this tutorial helped: [Using Entity Reference in Views](https://vimeo.com/30003605)